# Incrementing of variable inside a loop

Tags: c

What will be the output of the program?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int i = 0;
   while(i < 10)
    {
      i++;
      printf("%d\n",i);
    }
}
```

Will the output start from 0 or from 1 as I my professor taught me that the value of the variable is incremented only at the end of the loop while using i++ unlike in ++i?

Comment: Test it first. You can use https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Comment: The first printed value is `1`. There is no difference in **this** code whether you use `++i` or `i++`. If your professor says otherwise, make sure you understand him/her correctly. If you did understand correctly, run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The side effect of incrementing using either the prefix `++` or the postfix `++` occurs before the statement `i++;` completes.  The fact that the statement is in a loop doesn't change that.

Your professor is correct.  The first time `printf` is called in the loop, `i` will have the value 1 because the previous statement incremented the value.

Had you instead had the following code:

```
while(i < 10)
{
  printf("%d\n",i++);
}
```

Then 0 *would* be printed on the first iteration.  In this case, the value of `i` is incremented, but the postfix `++` operator means that the old value of `i` is passed to the `printf` call.

Answer (score 2):

will start from 1 since the line i++ ends before you enter the next line which prints, the ++i compared to i++  is different when you increment it while doing something else in the same line/command.
for example: if you use

```
printf("%d",i++);
```

it would print 0 before incrementing i but if you put it like this:

```
printf("%d",++i);
```

it will first increment i (from 0 to 1) and then print i(which is 1 the first time it's printed).

Answer (score 0):

Your code will print 1 as first value.

`i++` increments the value at the end of the *statement*, and vice versa `++i` increments the value before the statement. This is usually used when assigning variables:

```
i = 5;
int a = ++i; // a=6, i=6
i = 5;
int b = i++; // b=5, i=6
```

Comment: The side effect of increment occurs at some time **before** the statement completes. Saying an increment occurs **at the end** of the statement ould mislead somebody into believing `i++ * i;` is equivalent to `i*i; i++;`. Similarly, it is wrong to say `++i` increments the value before the statement. The value of `++i` is the value of `i` after the increment, and the value of `i++` is the value of `i` before the increment, but when the increment actually changes `i` is unspecified in general (although constrained by other issues, such as the end of the full expression).